# Isekai manhua where female lead dies and wakes up as a noble girl who can roll gacha

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

From what I remember the main character (MC) is a girl with pink hair who dies and comes back as a noble. That noble was sick and all their family members left them. There's like a bunny god of love who mortals can only see as a bunny or something. She rolls for like commanders and there's this half-naked dude with red hair. He and this other dude, who's a butler to the MC, are like battle brothers or something. Also, she meets a bunch of gods and they like her and stuff. I don't remember the name, so that's why I'm here.

Comment: An isekai manga where the protagonist is reborn in another world with cheats and attractive assistants? That is a surprise. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is ***[Chitra](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/23eztue/chitra)***.

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/chitra):

> I spent years preparing for the civil service exam. But I can’t believe I died so unfairly…! Is that so? I was reborn as a beautiful countess. I even got the ability to play games from the God of Beauty. ‘Drawing..? ’Yes, I have the ability to draw for characters. I have become the apostle of the God of Beauty and benefited the world widely by drawing out ultra rare characters. [Rare-!][Super Duper Ultra Special Rare-!!!] Let's fill the world with handsome men to benefit all the women!

A woman is playing a game on her smartphone while crossing the road, and is hit by a truck and killed. In the afterlife, she's approached by a rabbit-like being referring to himself as Phobinus, the God of Beauty. Phobinus offers her the chance to live a second life in exchange for her completing tasks for him in that life. He also says that he'll give her two gifts: the ability to play games in her new life, and an assistant.

She then wakes up in another world as Chitra Serekino, a sickly, pink-haired countess who was abandoned by her relatives. In her bedroom, there's a gacha machine that looks like a golden rabbit, and she has a ticket allowing her to use the machine once for free. After that, she has to earn faith points to use it again.

She uses the machine and it summons the 'Warrior Butler,' Radelk, an ancient hero who previously defeated the Demon King. He becomes her right-hand man from that point forward. Quite a bit later in the story, she uses the machine again, and it summons the 'Wizard Legendary Hero,' Tyrex, who has long red hair and wears a revealing costume. Radelk explains that Tyrex helped him defeat the Demon King in the past.

There are also references to various other gods in this world, such as the God of Lightning, the God of Plague, the God of War, and the Goddess of Domination.

[image] [image]